# Order in the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I would like others to tell me which sentence is written correctly.

1. One of my friends took me this photo.
2. One of my friends took this photo of me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct sentence is the second one - “One of my friends took this photo of me.”
Generally in English (particularly in spoken English) we don’t put any words between the verb (took) and what it applies to (this photo).
Hope this helps!